# What RPG allows me to run games for multiple teams of spirit/real characters?

Tags: game-recommendation

I've recently come up with an idea to play a campaign with player pairs.
Some players would be ritualists that made a pact with spirits to give them powers, and other players would be said spirits. I thought that could be a great thing to spice up our regular group and introduce a little bit of new and creative mechanics as well as a healthy amount of chaos and discussion between players.

My problem is that I don't have a game which currently has enough ways these people can interact. All of the games I've considered end up leaving one player with nothing to do for way too long.

The game needs tasks and mechanics to keep up the interaction and keep people meddling with their counterparts during most of the game. These must enable cooperative gameplay as well as enable them to antagonize each other from time to time.

I like how Shadowrun's spirit world works, for flavor and resource management, but the system doesn't do this style of play well.

Do any games support this style of gameplay?

Comment: If you have an answer to your question through additional research or experience, you should self-answer. Questions should contain questions. Also, [don't signal edits.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text) Comments are for requests for clarification only, not chatting. Go to [chat] to chat.

Comment: Why doesn't SR4 work for you?  I was about to suggest it as an answer when I saw you've already dismissed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two games I know of that each address part of your desired style - but neither covers it precisely.

### [Sorcerer](http://adept-press.com/games-fantasy-horror/sorcerer/)

Sorcerer addresses this exact scenario. From the back-cover blurb:

> In this role-playing game, the characters are people, not mutants or
>   monsters or elves. However, they are driven people, willing to
>   break the most fundamental laws of reality to achieve their goals.
>   ey know how to summon, bind, and command demons. But
>   demons are dangerous, transgressive beings, who demand a Price
>   for the power they lend ...
>   Your character commands unimaginable, horrific power with a
>   mind of its own. Can you handle it?

In this game, the **GM plays the demons**, which breaks the player-pairs you are looking for. But it is meant to play exactly the game you have described - people making pacts with dangerous spirits to access power beyond their own.

### [Better Angels](http://arcdream.com/home/better-angels/)

Better Angels is a supervillain roleplaying game where each player plays his own villain and the power-granting devil of another PC.

So while this game breaks **genre** - superheroes instead of ritualist casters - it does split the entity/vessel roles between players exactly as it seems you desire. Specifically, the villains need the devils and the devils need the villains - but they don't have the same goals. This creates the cooperative / antagonistic split you are looking for. In fact, it is the foundation of the game.

**NB:** While I do **own** and **have read** both games, I have no actual play experience with **either**. However, *Sorcerer* is a well-known and well-regarded pioneer in the indie RPG scene and there is ample evidence that the game successfully executes a player/GM split. I *have played* other One Roll Engine games (*Reign*, specifically) and can attest that the base system works well. The split presented in *Better Angels* has clear rules and clear roles for each player and appears to be a good implementation of the player/player split.

Answer (score 5):

The Old World of Darkness game [Wraith: the Oblivion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wraith:_The_Oblivion) has something that approximates this. Your main character is a ghost and your dark side (called a "Shadow") is actually a separate mini-character, controlled by a different player. During the game, your Shadow has several powers that it can use to make things difficult for you, either by tempting you into actions you wouldn't normally take, or outright opposing you.

This solves the problem of players having nothing to do: You play your main character most of the time, but during another player's spotlight time, their Shadow is plotting against them. The Shadow/Wraith relationship is presented as extremely antagonistic, but the basic idea is pretty ripe for adaptation.

The setting itself may not be what you wanted, but the player pairs mechanic would definitely be worth a look.

I did play an extremely short (2 to 3 session) Wraith campaign, and we did have quite a bit of interaction between the players and their "Shadow guides." It's a game that I hold in very high regard, but have never been able to set-up a full campaign, due to it's overall complexity.

Answer (score 1):

[Orpheus](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/771/Orpheus?term=orphe&it=1) is a Classic World of Darkness game that's built around interactions between the living, the spirits of the dead, and people who are able to interact with both.  PCs can spirits or living people who use various techniques to enter the spirit realms.

The game has a single core book with rules, and five supplements.  The five books comprise a playable campaign for the game.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like exactly the kind of 'What If?' campaign I have seen people prototype with [Fate Accelerated Edition](http://www.evilhat.com/home/fae/). It may be a viable option if you're looking for a rules-light way of representing the world while focusing on the interaction between players, and the spirit-shaman duality. I built a game using this with the premise that the players have NPC robotic animal drones which they control, but this could be very effective with spirits.

FAE has six stats, called Approaches, which are mostly about the how, not the what, of a character. Your ritualists and spirits would be built the same way - A Forceful shaman cajoles and threatens spirits, while a Forceful spirit might be more potent when fighting or making sweeping magical effects. In my example campaign, a hot-shot big game hunter or a leap-before-looking tiger drone could both be "High Forceful, Low Careful" characters.

FAE uses Aspects, or little one liners about the character, to represent details of character (and temporary ones to represent the rest of the world), like "Ancient spirit of the forest's largest oak" or "Last ritualist of the southern wolf tribe".

You can use these aspects as 'Permission' to allow players to take certain actions - Only someone with ritualist in their High Concept (main asapect) can negotiate a pact with a spirit, or summon them, etc. Maybe you need to have an aspect, either a permanent one with 'Spirit' in it, or create one (A ritualist might use an action to give themselves a 'Projected into the spirit world" aspect for example) before you can interact directly with something on the 'Other side'. Spirits could do the same to manifest in the real world or create effects. My players couldn't repair something that didn't have an aspect saying it was a drone, or try to train something without an animal in its aspects.

Aspects can be invoked if they help you, using a pile of Fate Points, or compelled, giving you more points if they interfere. So if one of your ritualist-tender pairs have aspects that infer some kind of interpersonal drama (Cursed by my ancestors / Vengeful but loving ancestor spirit) then you can give them a currency when that drama plays out, which can help them overcome other challenges. This is how my Drones game managed uppity drones or long term trouble for the team.

Comment: I do own Fate Core. But from what I gather it is slightly different from FAE, correct? I haven't tried it before because I was under the assumption that I needed more rules to keep both players engaged, not less.

I might have been mistaken though.

In this campaign you ran, the drones were NPCs controlled by the GM, correct?

Comment: @Althis Core would be better than Accelerated for this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Werewolf:The Apocalypse](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf:_The_Apocalypse) or [Mage: The Ascension](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Mage:_The_Ascension), where players often interact with the spirit world (Umbra). Umbra is vast and contains multiple dimensions - ranging from hell-like pits to serene Summer County, but most interesting is the Penumbra - a shadow reflection of mundane world. In those worlds multitude of spirits exist, both benevolent and evil (with are both quite subjective). I've found quite interesting [basic guide](http://www.mindseyesociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/WtA-Spirit-Guide-2.1.pdf) how to turn such spirits from NPC to playable characters.

Comment: Have you played this Nephilim? Can you tell if there is enough separation between the player and the spirit to make it work in my scenario? Can you tell me more about the mechanics that embolden the possession phase?

Comment: I've played it ages ago, but we were following the traditional route with simulacrum (host) already merged with the spirit of nephilim. My GM was showing great secrecy of the mechanic but I do remember that he mentioned (more than once) that it can be played from the mortal perspective. I'm trying to find more information about it, but it was never very popular system so there is not much information online.